# How to decode a base64 to an image discord.py and send it

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, base64

So I found this API which which helps in image manipulation. It gives the result in base64 format. I searched a lot but couldn't find how exactly to decode base64 to an image. Here is the code:-

```
@bot.command()
async def image(ctx, method=None):
  params = {'method': method, 'img1': 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'}
  header = {"Authorization": "mykey"}
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=header) as session:
    async with session.post(f'https://api.pgamerx.com/v5/canvas', params=params) as resp:
      res = await resp.json()
      data = res[0]["base64"]
      print(data)
```

I print the data to get the base64 string and it was pretty huge and almost crashed my pc while pasting it. Any help would be appreciated.

(Note) There is no problem with the code, everything works fine

Comment: Have you really searched a lot? I just googled `python base64 to image and the first result had the answer.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase it, I did not understand how to send the decoded image as a file on discord. I am receiving from the API the encoding and not able to figure out how to convert it and send it directly without saving it to my directory.

Comment: Use encode() . It encodes things to base64

Comment: @DjWalkzz He wants to decode as the post states "couldn't find how exactly to decode base64 to an image"

Comment: Sorry then `decode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import io, base64  # Add these imports to the top of the file

@bot.command()
async def image(ctx, method=None):
  params = {'method': method, 'img1': 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'}
  header = {"Authorization": "mykey"}
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=header) as session:
    async with session.post(f'https://api.pgamerx.com/v5/canvas', params=params) as resp:
      res = await resp.json()
      data = res[0]["base64"]
      print(data)
      file = discord.File(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
      await ctx.send(file=file)
```

This uses [base64.b64decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) to decode the base64 encoded string, then wraps the result in a [bytesio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) so that it can be read by discord.File